# OnBind() on service always returns False - Android

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-service, android-context

I'm trying to bind a service, but `onBind()` always returns false.

This is the code for the `ServiceConnection`-

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // This is called when the connection with our service has been established, 
        // giving us the service object we can use to interact with our service.
        mBoundService = ((ScheduleService.ServiceBinder) service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mBoundService = null;
    }
};
```

This is call to `bindService()` -

```
boolean test = getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(this, ScheduleService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

This is the declaration of the service in the Manifest -

```
<service android:name=".Notifications.ScheduleService" android:enabled="true"/>
```

I've read previous questions regarding the subject and couldn't find an answer(tried switching the Activity context with the Application context, but it didn't help).

I'm using using Frgaments and ActionBarSherlock, and my Activity extends `SlidingFragmentActivity` (That's why i'm using the application context, which doesn't help).

Edit - This is the code of the service i'm trying to start -

```
public class ScheduleService extends Service {

    /**
     * Class for clients to access
     */
    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public ScheduleService getService() {
            return ScheduleService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("ScheduleService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients. See
    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

    /**
     * Show an alarm for a certain date when the alarm is called it will pop up a notification
     */
    public void setAlarm(Calendar c) {
        // This starts a new thread to set the alarm
        // You want to push off your tasks onto a new thread to free up the UI to carry on responding
        new AlarmTask(this, c).run();
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated . Thanks.

Comment: I think you should remove the .Notifications in the Manifest.

Comment: Post your service implementation code.

Comment: I edited the question with the implementation.

Comment: You mean bindService() returns false?

Answer (score 1):

What is the fully qualified class-name of `ScheduleService` (i.e. including the full package-name)?

I'm asking this, because in your AndroidManifest.xml file, your service's name is `.Notifications.ScheduleService`, which seems a bit odd:

This tells me that either

- The (last part of the) package-name contains a ***upper-case***
  character... not so good.
  I would expect `.notifications.ScheduleService` instead, if this is the case.
- The `ScheduleService` is defined within a file called Notifications.java.
  I would expect `.Notifications$ScheduleService` instead, if this is the case (dollar sign instead of period).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `bindService()` returns false?  `onBind()` returns `IBinder` type.

Keep in mind that service binding takes some time.  If you want to perform some action after binding is done you can perform it in the `onServiceConnected()` method.

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

    mBoundService = ((ScheduleService.ServiceBinder) service).getService();
    Calendar c = new Calendar();
    mBoundService.setAlarm(c);
}
```

If you need more guidance on this you need to show us your Activity code.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use the application context to bind the service?
The method bindService is called through the ContextWrapper. It might not be the issue but I'd share contexts across the place where you bind the service and where you have the connection.

In your case instead of

```
boolean test = getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(this, ScheduleService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

I'd do the following

```
boolean test = bindService(new Intent(this, ScheduleService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Or if you want to keep a global context within the application, move everything to your Application file and call it similarly the same way suggested above.

The issue can also be on the package name of your app and the declaration of your service in your manifest. If you are unsure make sure to give the global route to your service in the manifest.